# DBCC CHECKDB Job Fails: Error Says Deadlock Exists But Cannot Determine Why

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a nightly sql agent job which executes the DBCC CheckDB. This week it has started failing while it runs. The error message says that there is a deadlock.

We could not determine what was causing the deadlock. So we rebooted the server during off hours last night before the job ran again and it still failed.

We would like to know what is causing this to happen. How can we see what has caused the deadlock?

**Environment:** 
SQL Server 2005

**SQL Agent Job Code:**

```
truncate table master..tbl_dbccresults;
insert into master..tbl_dbccresults
exec master..sp_msforeachdb @command1 = 'dbcc checkdb (?) with tableresults';
```

**Error Details:**

```
Executed as user: xxxxx\xxxxxx. Transaction (Process ID 76) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. 

[SQLSTATE 40001] (Error 1205)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528)  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 2528).  The step failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot SQL Server deadlock issues, you'd better to enable -1222 trace flag on the server so that deadlock information will be logged in the SQL Server error log which you can use for further investigation. You can use SQL Server profiler to trace deadlock events as well. I would recommend the following serial blog post about troubleshooting SQL Server deadlock issues, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx.

Comment: I assume you are suggesting that I execute "DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1)" in a query window before the job runs. Then analyze the output, and run "DBCC TRACEOFF (1222, -1)?